# Deploying C# web applicatin with ajaxtoolkit throws exception

Tags: reference

My web application runs normally on my dev computer but when I tried to deploy it ISS 6.0 Windows server 2003 it gives this error:

> The requested script resource 'Common.Common.js' requires version 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.60623.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' of the ASP.NET AJAX Framework. To use this resource, make sure that the application references version 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.60623.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e'.

Help me fix this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place ajax AjaxControlToolkit.dll in Bin Folder and add project reference to that Bin DLL. Build and deploy.

Even if it doesnt work then also put system.Extension.dll in Bin Folder and give reference.

Hope this will work..